# c# parsing data from wikipedia through html-agility-pack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to extract the release date of the film from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aisa_Pyaar_Kahan) link.

The problem is that it is given directly in a `<td>` tag, which has no class or id. The only possible solution that I can think of is using the style tag to extract data but I have no idea on how to do it.

Here's my code

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + textBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "_");
try
{
    foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(/*?*/))
    {
        label1.Text+=node.InnerText;
    }                                
}
catch (Exception ex3) { }
```

Please help!

Comment: Why don't you just use the [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php)? Or since you want to get info about a movie the [API of some movie db](https://developer.fandango.com/Rotten_Tomatoes)? Honestly, downloading a wiki-page and manually parsing it would be the **last** thing I'd do.

Comment: @Manfred Radlwimmer its sorta project and im only allowed to use html-agility-pack

Comment: If by that you mean it's some sort of school assignment, then whoever is teaching you is leading you down a very wrong path.

Comment: Its not a school project @Manfred Radlwimmer

Comment: Then who's stopping you from doing this *the right way*? The html-agility-pack has it's uses and familiarity with it doesn't hurt but it should be a last resort. When a site offers APIs, WebServices, RSS or anything similar - use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath expression gives you the element you need:

```
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[14]/td
```

Pro tip: Open Chrome debugger tools, navigate to the element you are searching for, right click and hit "Copy > Copy xpath".

Suggestion: The XPath expression seems rather brittle. Sometimes it makes more sense trying to extract specific parts of the HTML with RegEx, which might lead to a more stable solution. However, [don't try to parse HTML with Regex!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: table[1] and tr[14] are using index. On a different wiki page, this will not work. I think it is better to retrieve the whole table and check for the correct th element with the text 'Release Date'

Comment: True! As I said, at this point it might make sense to use RegEx or just iterate over the table rows.